# WebSphere Application Server EJB Optimization

Tags: optimization, ejb, websphere

We are working on developing a Java EE based application. Our application is Java 1.5 compatible and will be deployed to WAS ND 6.1.0.21 with EBJ 3.0 and Web Services feature packs. The configuration is currently one cell with two clusters. Each cluster will have two nodes.

Our application, or our system, as I should rather say, comes in two or three parts.

Part 1: An ear deployed to one cluster that contains 3rd party vendor code combined with customization code. Their code is EJB 2.0 compliant and has a lot of Remote Home interfaces.

Part 2: An ear deployed to the same cluster as the first ear. This ear contains EBJ 3's that make calls into the EJB 2's supplied by the vendor and the custom code. These EJB 3's are used by the JSF UI also packaged with the EAR, and some of them are also exposed as web services (JAX-WS 2.0 with SOAP 1.2 compliance) for other clients.

Part 3: There may be other services that do not depend on our vendor/custom code app. These services will be EJB 3.0's and web services that are deployed to the other cluster.

Per a recommendation from some IBM staff on site here, communication between nodes in a cluster can be EJB RMI. But if we are going across clusters and/or other cells, then the communication should be web services.

That said, some of us are wondering about performance and optimizing communication for speed of our applications that will use our web services and EJB's. Right now most EJB's are exposed as remote. (and our vendor set theirs up that way, rather than also exposing local home interfaces). We are wondering if WAS does any optimizations between apps in the same node/cluster node space. If two apps are installed in the same area and they call each other via remote home interface, is WAS smart enough to make it a local home interface call?

Are their other optimization techniques? Should we consider them? Should we not? What are the costs/benefits? Here is the question from one of our team members as sent in their email:

The question is: Supposing we develop our EJBs as remote EJBs, where our UI controller code is talking to our EXT java services via EJB3...what are our options for performance optimization when both the EJB server and client are running in the same container?

As one point of reference, google has given me some oooooold websphere performance tuning documentation from 2000 that explains a tuning configuration you can set to enable Call By Reference for EJB communication when they're in the same application server JVM. It states the following:

Because EJBs are inherently location independent, they use a remote programming
model. Method parameters and return values are serialized over RMI-IIOP and returned
by value. This is the intrinsic RMI "Call By Value" model.

WebSphere provides the "No Local Copies" performance optimization for running EJBs
and clients (typically servlets) in the same application server JVM. The "No Local
Copies" option uses "Call By Reference" and does not create local proxies for called
objects when both the client and the remote object are in the same process. Depending
on your workload, this can result in a significant overhead savings.

Configure "No Local Copies" by adding the following two command line parameters to
the application server JVM:

```
* -Djavax.rmi.CORBA.UtilClass=com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.Util
* -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.iiop.noLocalCopies=true
```

CAUTION: The "No Local Copies" configuration option improves performance by
changing "Call By Value" to "Call By Reference" for clients and EJBs in the same JVM.
One side effect of this is that the Java object derived (non-primitive) method parameters
can actually be changed by the called enterprise bean. Consider Figure 16a:

Also, we will also be using Process Server 6.2 and WESB 6.2 as well in the future. Any ideas? recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: I think this setting (enable Call By Reference) is applicable only for EJB remote interfaces not for EJB Local interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only automatic optimization that can really be done for remote EJBs is if they are colocated (accessed from within the same JVM).  In that case, the ORB will short-circuit some of the work that would otherwise be required if the request needed to go across the wire.  There will still be some necessary ORB overhead including object serialization (unless you turn on noLocalCopies, with all the caveats it brings).

Alternatively, if you know that the UI controller is colocated, your method calls do not rely on parameter or return value copying, and your interface does not rely on the exception differences between local and remote views, then you could create and expose a local subinterface that will be much faster than remote access through the ORB.